# Why do Frame rate falls to decimals after few seconds for Three.js?

Tags: 3d, webgl, three.js

```
<script>

        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var scale = 100, N=1000;
        var arr= [];
        var width = 720, height = 405;


         function average(v)
         {
              var items = v.length;
              var sum = 0.0;
              for (i = 0; i<items; i++)
              sum += v[i];
              return (sum/items);
            }

        start =function()
        {
        init();
        //animate();
        };      

        function init() 
        {

            container = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 0.1, 10000 );
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            camera.position.z = 80;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

            renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);
            renderer.setSize( width, height );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            for ( var i = 0; i <= N; i++)
            {
                arr.push(new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ));
                arr[i].position.set( (Math.random()-0.5) * scale, (Math.random()-0.5) * scale, (Math.random()-0.5) * scale ); 
                scene.add( arr[i] );


            }
            animate();
            document.getElementById('3dobjects').innerHTML = "Three.js Demo, The number of Cube Objects: " +N;
            }

        function animate() 
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }


        function render() 
        {   

            var t = 0;
            var t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
            var fpss = [];
            setInterval(function(){
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                var t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
                fpss.push(1000/(t1 - t0));
                if(fpss.length>200)
                  fpss.shift();

                if(t%2==0)
                    document.getElementById('fpsout').innerHTML = "FPS coded Myself is: " +average(fpss);   
            t0 = t1;
                t++;
          },1000/60);

        }
```

Why the frame rate falls to decimals after few seconds for Three.js application? Am I calling the fps calculation at wrong place? If possible can someone help me for the basic shader program for rendering simple cube without texture but color.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by tweaking stats.js and accessing the FPS from it.